# Symfony - Authorization header in Postman

Tags: symfony, postman, request-headers

I have a problem with passing of Authorization header.
In Sf 3.2.7 I was passing a header with Postman like this:
Authorization Bearer {token}

Now, in sf 3.2.8 the Authorization header doesn't arrive

I have a unit test that testing my controller and I have setup the client in this way and works

```
    $this->client->request('GET', "/Hotel/{$aHotel->id()->id()}", [], [], [
        'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' => "Bearer {$this->token}"
    ]);
```

Postman has stopped working

I thought that the htaccess should solve the problem with this lines:

```
# Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

But nothing to do...

---

**SOLUTION**

The problem was in the apache virtual host.
The directory in "" directive was wrong
So, I have correct the folder of my project and the Authorization header has started to work

Comment: `Hotel/{$aHotel->id()->id()` doesn't seem ok, where is the closing bracket ?

Comment: @COil it's only an example... the code works. The problem is not there. By the way I have correct the example

Comment: Would you kindly add the answer to the question?
I have the same problem.